# To get the Error_Number() from the stored procedure to the calling .NET application

Tags: c#, exception, ado.net, sqldatareader

Hi what is the best way to pass the `Error_Number()` from the stored procedure to the calling .NET application?

I know we can do it by setting an output parameter or through a `SELECT` query.

Note: I am using a data reader.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to do this - catch your `Error_number()` in a SQL `try/catch` block and then raise an error, which you can catch in your .NET application as a `SqlException`.

In your SQL stored procedure:

```sql
BEGIN TRY
   -- do something here....
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   DECLARE @ErrorNumber INT

   SELECT @ErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER() 

   RAISERROR
(N'The error code is: %d',
     16, -- Severity.
      1, -- State.
     @ErrorNumber,     -- First substitution argument.
     '');              -- Second substitution argument.
END CATCH;
```

and in your .NET code (here: C#):

```
// call your stored proc some way...
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("server=.;database=Test;Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.YourStoredProcNameHere", conn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    // possibly add parameters to the stored procedure call....

    try
    {
       conn.Open();
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       conn.Close();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {  
       // catch SqlException - ex.ErrorNumber contains your error number
       string msg = string.Format("Error number: {0} / Message: {1}", ex.Number, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks . Iam working with datareader. Will this solution works for Data Reader ?

Comment: @Ananth: if a `RAISERROR` happens in SQL Server, your C# code is interrupted with an exception - and your data reader is aborted, and control goes to the `catch` in the `try/catch` block in your .NET app. So yes - it works with a datareader ....

Comment: @marc_s.. I got the answer i was looking for..It is ex.Number which has the error number..Thanks..But raise error did not work with data reader. The select query in the sp worked  fine and the an error was never raised though RAISERROR statement was written just after the SELECT query

Comment: how can I use this method when  ROLLBACK TRAN is used in a catch block ? When I use ROLLBACK TRAN keyword, aps.net does not get into exception block

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
BEGIN TRY
    -- Generate a constraint violation error.

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;


END CATCH;
```

Comment: @Royi..Thanks. .But us there any other solution than a SELECT query ?. Like I need to know if any property of commandobject or reader will be set with the error number.